# How to imagine a real Substrate app?

Tags: substrate-node, substrate-front-end, substrate-connect

How to imagine a real Substrate application?

I am trying to make an application, where you can trade your own product. You can advertise product, buy, list, see your earlier purchases, etc...

If I start a substrate node on local, I am able to connect to it with my own front-end and place products on chain. But it is local... What about a real world application? Every users have to start their own substrate node, and after that they have to join to it with my front-end? I think it is a little complicated processing.

Please, somebody clear it to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of it as the backend of your application. In web2 you do not ask your users to run your backend and similar here, we do not expect our users to run our blockchain. Where it differs is that you could run your blockchain yourself by running servers (probably in the cloud) that run your Substrate blockchain, or you could build a decentralized community that is incentivized to run your blockchain.

The best place to start, for you, may be with smart contracts. Take a look at [Moonbeam](https://moonbeam.network) which runs Substrate and allows for smart contracts. So you would build your frontend app on top of a Moonbeam smart contract that you write that you deploy on the Moonbeam parachain (which is a Substrate blockchain running on Polkadot).

OR even better, start here:

- https://fleek.xyz
- https://apillon.io

If you do want to build your own custom Substrate blockchain then you can start here:

- https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/substrate/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Bruno explained very well the options you have for a real Substrate application.

To answer your question about users: no! users don't have to start their own substrate node, they should only have to interact with your frontend application.

In the [Front-end-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template) you can see an example on how to interact with a node and with [ink!athon Boilerplate](https://github.com/scio-labs/inkathon#inkathon-boilerplate) you will find a starter kit for full-stack dApp development with ink! smart contracts

Follow this discussion in the Polkadot Forum: [Frontend Development Experience](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/frontend-development-experience/4393) where you will find different resources the develop your frontend application.